# Why my Mob Grinder/Farm isn't working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I built (by following tutorials, see below) a Mob Grinder. It's a simple 20x20, with water, etc.

[image: The Mob Grinder/Farm]

But when I go up there, it's not dark inside. I don't use Gammabright and I didn't put torches or anything.

[image: I'm not using Gammabright, torches, and there's no holes in the spawner!][image: The hole that mobs fall into is lighted too!]

I went to have dinner and put hoppers in the ground and stood 1 block away from the spawner, to see if some mob spawn and falls. But I got just 5 bones, 2 strings, 1 gunpowder and 4 rotten flesh, which is far less spawns than in the video.

I'm playing on multiplayer, but I'm very far away from other players. I saw in other topics, that we need to stop the mob spawning in the area around me, then they will get more chances to spawn in my trap, but it doesn't works, I don't know what to do!

When I'm on the top of the spawner, the Y is 96, and when I'm on the ground, the Y is 65. By the way, I think the problem isn't the nether rack, 'cause I see on the gamepedia, and it says: "Usage: Netherrack can be used as part of a trapping mechanism for Mob farming."

Tutorial Video:

Comment: No, it's a diferent problem :/ - VERY DIFERENT!

Comment: I'm not sure how; you're both asking why your mob spawner isn't working.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your spawner. If you haven't lit up all the surrounding caves, you'll get a lower spawn rate. Also mobs won't spawn within 16 blocks of a player so if you were near it you may have been stopping some from working.

Comment: actually mobs won't spawn within 24 blocks of a player according to the wiki: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Spawn#Mob_spawning

Comment: @Psytro could you explain how this is "VERY DIFFERENT" from the other question ?

Comment: So, I just need to walk 24 blocks away from the trap, and the mobs will spawn?

Answer (score 4):

You need to be 24 blocks away from the spawner for mobs to spawn. Also, if you're within 128 blocks of the ground and haven't lit the caves up, most of the mobs will spawn in the caves. Either AFK 128 blocks from the ground or light up some caves. Make sure you're within 128 blocks of the landing pad for the mobs though.

Another thing, when there are other players on, the mob cap is split between all players in 1.7 versions and below. If you are playing in 1.8 snapshots, that doesn't apply.

As far as it being bright in there, you need to make sure it's all closed off when you're inside to see if it's dark. If it's still bright, try hitting F3+A to reload the chunks and see if that updates the lighting.

Comment: I don't understand this part: "Also, if you're within 128 blocks of the ground and haven't lit the caves up, most of the mobs will spawn in the caves. Either AFK 128 blocks from the ground or light up some caves. Make sure you're within 128 blocks of the landing pad for the mobs though." Please, explain to me.

Comment: Mobs instantly despawn when they're more than 128 blocks away, so #1 - you need to be 128 blocks away from any dark spots where you DON'T want mobs to spawn, and #2 - closer than 128 blocks from the farm where you DO want mobs to spawn. Furthermore, mobs despawn over time when they're more than 30 blocks away, but that is a much slower process. They would hopefully make it through your trap and be killed before that happens.

Comment: Glad to hear it! If I have provided a satisfactory answer, please consder reading "What do I do when someone answers my question?": http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers